# Certain urls dont load in webview

Tags: android, url, webview, loading

I have a working webview that i modify to load different urls. This site doesn't load. It just shows a blank scree and yes i have the right permissions. Here's the code:

public class PowerSchoolActivity extends Activity {

```
private static final String TAG = "PowerSchool 2";
public static final String url = null;
private WebView mWebView;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Log.i(TAG, "onCreate");
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("https://pschool.fsd1.org/teachers/pw.html");
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new PowerSchoolClient());
    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the "https" in the url

The solution: 
http://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2010/09/28/android-webview-with-https-loadurl-shows-blankempty-page/

Comment: where would i place this engine = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.my_webview);
engine.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
 public void onReceivedSslError (WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
 handler.proceed() ;
 }
}